# Query List of IP addresses from SQL Database

Tags: sql, powershell

I am using powershell to

1. Take IP address from a list of IP addresses
2. Plug it into SQL query
3. Output result

So far, the code only works if I include one IP address. If I include more than one the script hangs indefinitely

This code seems correct, what should be fixed?

```
$file = Get-Content C:\list.txt

$conn.Open()

foreach ($k in $file){
    write-host $k

    $sql = "SELECT dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME,[IP_ADDR1_TEXT],(dbo.SEM_AGENT.FREE_DISK/1073741824)as 'Free Disk Space (GB)', 
    (dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.DISK_TOTAL/1073741824) as 'Total Disk Space (GB)',
    (dbo.SEM_AGENT.FREE_MEM/1073741824) as 'Free Memory (GB)', (dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.MEMORY/1073741824) as 'Total Memory (GB)', 
    dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM,NAME, SEM_AGENT.MAJOR_VERSION
    FROM dbo.sem_computer, [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER], dbo.IDENTITY_MAP, dbo.SEM_CLIENT, dbo.SEM_AGENT
    WHERE [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
    AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
    AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
    AND dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_AGENT.COMPUTER_ID
    AND [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '$k'"

    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$conn)

    do{
    try{
        $rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

        # Read Computer Name, Computer ID, IP address, Domain, and Operating System from the Database into a multidimensional array

        while ($rdr.read()){
            $sql_output += ,@($rdr.GetValue(0), $rdr.GetValue(1), $rdr.GetValue(2), $rdr.GetValue(3), $rdr.GetValue(4), $rdr.GetValue(5), $rdr.GetValue(6), $rdr.GetValue(7), $rdr.GetValue(8))
        }
        $transactionComplete = $true
    }
    catch{
        $transactionComplete = $false
    }
    }until ($transactionComplete)
}

Write-host $sql_output

$conn.Close()
```

Comment: Have you considered building your Sql Connection within the for loop?  Also, if there is an error writing to $sql_output, you will run forever.  For troubleshooting, I would write-host $sql to ensure the text is right and then spend my time ensuring that you are working with the reader correctly.

Comment: I'd added the comment as an answer.  If you do not mind, was it just the SQL connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was the answer (from comments):

> Have you considered building your Sql Connection within the for loop?
>   Also, if there is an error writing to $sql_output, you will run
>   forever. For troubleshooting, I would write-host $sql to ensure the
>   text is right and then spend my time ensuring that you are working
>   with the reader correctly

Comment: I built the SQL Connection within the for loop by moving $conn.Open() into the for loop

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just test if this works first:

```
$file = Get-Content C:\list.txt

$conn.Open()

foreach ($k in $file){
    write-host $k

    $sql = "SELECT dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME,[IP_ADDR1_TEXT],(dbo.SEM_AGENT.FREE_DISK/1073741824)as 'Free Disk Space (GB)', 
    (dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.DISK_TOTAL/1073741824) as 'Total Disk Space (GB)',
    (dbo.SEM_AGENT.FREE_MEM/1073741824) as 'Free Memory (GB)', (dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.MEMORY/1073741824) as 'Total Memory (GB)', 
    dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM,NAME, SEM_AGENT.MAJOR_VERSION
    FROM dbo.sem_computer, [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER], dbo.IDENTITY_MAP, dbo.SEM_CLIENT, dbo.SEM_AGENT
    WHERE [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
    AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
    AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
    AND dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_AGENT.COMPUTER_ID
    AND [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '$k'"

    $command = $conn.CreateCommand()
    $command.CommandText = $sql
    $sql_output = $command.ExecuteReader()
}

Write-host $sql_output

$conn.Close()
```

Then add error-handling (try/catch) afterwards.